# Probability of the sum of two dice being less than six, knowing that said sum is a multiple of 4

Tags: probability

> Two dice are thrown, What is the probability that the sum of the two faces of the dice is less than 6, if we know that said sum is a multiple of 4?

These kinds of exercises are not my forte, but I'm pretty sure my answer is correct. The solution given is $\frac{3}{10}$, but I think the real solution is $\frac39$, I realized this is conditional probability, so I did $$\frac{\frac{3}{36}}{\frac{9}{36}}$$
Which gave me my answer. Are there any errors? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you.  There are $3$ ways to get $4$, $5$ ways to get $8$ and $1$ way to get $12$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. 
However, if you exchange the conditional statements like this.

What is the probability that the said sum is a multiple of 4 given that sum of the two faces of the dice is less than 6?

Then the answer would be 3/10. (which is the given solution according to you)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that, the statement has no ambiguity, so I guess either someone messed up either in the statement, or the solutions.